# How to pass a parameter to another View in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model called Year, and a Model called Highlight

A Year has and belongs to many highlights. And a highlight, has and belongs to many years. As this:

```
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :highlights

end

class Highlight < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :years
end
```

I have a view on the Year entity and want to have a button that links to all highlights of that specific year, for example:

```
 <td>
 <%= button_to 'Highlights', admin_highlights_path(year), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %>
</td>
```

I know what to do on my controller, but Im doing something wrong on this view. Because, when I click the button it show the message:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in Admin::HighlightsController#create
```

Because, of course this is trying to go to the wrong action.

So, my question is, how to generate a button that send the year as parameter for the admin_highlight index, and in my controller I can show all the highlights categories for that specific year?

My routes:

```
namespace :admin do
    root 'pages#show', id: 'dashboard'

    resources :events
    resources :invitees do
      collection do
        get 'import_invitees/:year' => 'invitees#import_invitees', as: :import_invitees
      end
    end
    resources :highlights

    resources :pages
    resources :speakers
    resources :sponsors
    resources :users
    resources :years do
      resources :events do
        resources :photos
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes please?

Comment: [`button_to` helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) calls a `POST` request by default. If you want to return an index view of Highlight, change for a `link_to` or specify the method

Comment: Thanks sovalina. But how to send the year parameter as a value ?

Comment: Use rails' link_to helper as sovalina said and provide it a key/value pair in the url options to send params. Ex.  <%= link_to "highlights", admin_highlights_path(year: year), class: 'btn btn-sm btn-default' %>. Then you'd be able to access that year as a param in your controller by params[:year]

Answer (score 0):

While defining the path to the button you should pass the year as a param.
Thats look like as follow:
`routes_path(key: value)` ex: `admin_highlights_path(year: year)`