# How to make a query on a has_many_and_belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance called Year and another called HighlightCategory. Just like this:

```
class HighlightCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :years 
end

class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :highlightCategories
end
```

Im doing a controller that wants to check all the HighlightCategories from a specific year. Like this:

```
if (params[:year])
    @year = Year.where(year: params[:year] )
    @subjects = HighlightCategory.where(HOW TO MAKE IT)
else
```

I want to make a query where I just return the HighlightCategories that have association with this specific year.

How can I make it?

Comment: `@subjects=@year.highlightcategories`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623681/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-another-view-in-ruby-on-rails), you pass a `year` instance as a params of your link_to.
In your controller it returns an id not an object of year.

So you can retrieve the corresponding year like this:

```
@year = Year.find(params[:year])
```

Then you have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between `Year` and `HighlightCategory`. To find the highlights_categories for this specific year you can just do:

```
@subjects = @year.highlights_categories
```

However, **be careful of your model and table naming convention**:
`HighlightCategory` model name must have a `highlight_categories` table name, with underscore ([source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)).
And the relationship for `Year`must be:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :highlight_categories
```

Comment: I do a ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
 => ["companies", "events", "events_speakers", "friendly_id_slugs", "highlight_categories", "highlight_categories_years", "highlights", "invitees", "pages", "photos", "schema_migrations", "speakers", "sponsors", "users", "years"]

So, my table name is correct. So, why when I do a Year.highlight_categories, it says "no method found"  ?

Comment: because `highlight_categories` is an instance method (for a specific year instance, [added by the relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection)), not a class method of `Year`

Comment: Sorry. Im doing y = Year.last and then y.highlight_categories and theres when the "no method found" error appears

Comment: your relationship in `Year` model has the good typo like this : `has_and_belongs_to_many :highlight_categories` ?

Comment: Now it works (on console). Thank you. But on the app, it keeps returning nothing. This is the query that is being made: 

 HighlightCategory Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `highlight_categories`.* FROM `highlight_categories` INNER JOIN `highlight_categories_years` ON `highlight_categories_years`.`highlight_category_id` = `highlight_categories`.`id` INNER JOIN `years` ON `years`.`id` = `highlight_categories_years`.`year_id` WHERE `years`.`year` IN (SELECT `years`.`id` FROM `years` WHERE `years`.`year` = 2014)
  Rendered admin/highlight_categories/index.html.erb within admin/layouts/application (0.6ms)

Comment: It works with:         @subjects = HighlightCategory.joins(:years).where(years: {year: params[:year]})

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
@subjects = HighlightCategory.joins(:years).where(years: {year: params[:year]})
```

using joins adds the table to your query, and this allows you to query from your years table

Answer (score 0):

Eager loaded:

```
@subjects = HighlightCategory.includes(:years).where(years: { year: @year })
```

Lazy loaded:

```
@subjects = HighlightCategory.joins(:years).where(years: { year: @year })
```

You can read about `joins` vs `includes` over [here](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/).

In short, while iterating over the collection in `@subjects`, if the `joins` is used then the data will be lazy loaded whereas `includes` will eager load all the records in the memory.

Both have their own use-cases.

Comment: It returns a empty dataset too :/

Comment: Can you dump the output?

Comment: I put a puts on the @subjects and it returns empty

Comment: When I make the same on the rails console: 

hc = HighlightCategory.last
hc.years

#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Year id: 14, year: 2027, register_link: "", registration_open: false, slug: "2027", save_the_date_file_name: ""...........etc.....

Comment: But if i get the Year, and try to make year.higlight_categories, it shows a "non method" error  y.highlight_categories
NoMethodError: undefined method `highlight_categories' for #<Year::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000077768f0>